# StreamWriter.WriteAsync in using block is failing to write entire file when Windows Service stops

Tags: c#, windows-services, streamwriter

I have the following innocuous snippet of code:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    await sw.WriteAsync(msg.BodyText);
}
```

This is in an async task running on a background thread of a Windows Service. The task is essentially a message pump that reads from a message queue and writes the messages to disk. This is the only line of code that writes to the file system.

There are a number of these message pump tasks. They are initialized like so:

```
_tasks = _config.MessagePumps.Select((pump) =>
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        StartMessagePump(pump, _source.Token), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}).ToArray();
```

I know that StreamWriter uses buffering during write operations for performance reasons and that wrapping it in a using block ensures the buffer is flushed when the StreamWriter is disposed. The Task that invokes this code does support cancellation *between* processing a la

```
while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var msg = await GetNextMessage();
    await SaveMessage(msg);
}
```

When the service is stopped, the `OnStop` event handler calls `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` followed by `Task.WaitAll()` to synchronously wait for all background tasks to complete like so:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    _source.Cancel();
    Task.WaitAll(_tasks);
}
```

The problem is that when I inspect the written files after the service has stopped any files that were actively being written at the time the stop was initiated are incomplete. Is there something obvious I'm overlooking? Can you offer any troubleshooting advice?

Comment: Is this a durable queue (e.g. MSMQ)?  If so, were the messages still enqueued that were not written to the file?

Comment: It is a durable queue (Websphere MQ). If an exception occurs the read is rolled back so the message can be read again. I left out the exception handling and rollback code for simplicity's sake. Unfortunately, no exception is occuring. The write operation appears to complete normally yet the tail end of the message is missing from the file.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll()` has a few overloads, but all of them take a Task[] as an argument.  Where are you keeping a list of the active tasks to wait for the completion of?

Comment: The SCM will kill your service if it doesn't stop in a reasonable amount of time. So is it possible that `SaveMessage` is taking a long time? There's a minor issue where `GetNextMessage` should really take a `CancellationToken`, but other than that the code looks fine to me.

Comment: I updated the question to include the `_tasks` array initialization as requested. The way it's written, it's certainly possible for either GetNextMessage or SaveMessage to take a long time. However, in this case the messages are relatively small and even though it is currently configured to create 10 tasks, the service stops in less than a second. IIRC, the SCM waits at least 30 seconds before forcibly shutting down an unresponsive service.

Comment: The tasks in your array `_tasks` are not the same tasks as are being returned from WriteAsync. You can check this with the thread id. Try switching to `sw.Write(msg.BodyText)` as this appears is already inside the async `SaveMessage` method.